# ggplot2: can I plot at the edge of plot canvas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2.  I want to make a plot where I mark certain points at the upper edge of the plotting canvas with red symbols.  Something like that:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:1)
markings <- function() {
    d2 <- data.frame(x=c(1.5,2.5), y=3)
    geom_point(data=d2, aes(x=x, y=y), col="red")
}
ggplot(data=d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + markings()
```

[image: Example figure, red dots are certain markers at the upper edge]

The problem is that `markings()` function does not know where is the upper edge of the figure (the value 3 is unknown.)  In the ordinary graphics I can use `par("usr")` to find the y-value of the upper edge, is there any solution to force the points to be at the upper edge of the graph in ggplot2?

Comment: you can use `Inf`, but that will really live on the edge. Otherwise you'll need to build the plot (`ggplot_build`) and extract the scale limit from there.

Comment: Wow, I did not think about that.  It is not too pretty but may be good enough :-)

Comment: I broadly know about ```ggplot_build``` but that would kill the nice ```marking()``` function.  I can also set the ```ylim``` based on the data (```3:1``` in this example) but in that case I have to calculate it separately and pass to ```markings```.  I think there may exist a way to either tell ggplot not to transform y or maybe to jump to grid drawing tools underneath.

Comment: if you want the end of the scale, there is no way around building the plot because each layer can have a different range data and only after training the scales are the limits available. If on the other hand you just want some spacing from the edge, there would be other options that don't require the build info.

Comment: You could change your code in the following way, first `p <- ggplot(data=d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))` (and any other layers you want), then calculate the maximum y value in the `ggplot` object `p` by using `max.y <- max(unlist(lapply(ggplot_build(plt)$data, function(x) max(x$y))))`.  If you modify `markings` to take the max `y` value, as in `p + markings(max.y)`, that should plot what you are asking for.  There may be a cleaner way to do this but this should work. I would add as an answer but @baptiste pretty much pointed to that (i.e. he should put up the answer to get credit).

Comment: If you're `geom_`s are all identity mapped, why not just pre-calculate the x & y ranges ahead of time? This whole thing doesn't really seem like an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use `geom_rug`.  Sorry, I am still
not quite thinking in the ggplot way...

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:1)
markings <- function() {
    d2 <- data.frame(x=c(1.5,2.5))
    geom_rug(data=d2, aes(x=x), col="red", sides="t")
}
ggplot(data=d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + markings()
```

[image: Close to what I wanted--using <code>geom_rug()</code>]

Thank you guys for your help :-)